# What is the equivalent to `0 08-18 * * *`(crontab) in mesos-chronos?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, mesos-chronos

I have read the documentation how to add a scheduled job https://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/api.html#adding-a-scheduled-job

Although I don't know how to do it.

I would like to execute a job in mesos-chronos `At minute 0 past every hour from 8 through 18.`

In crontab is something like:

`0 08-18 * * *`

What is the equivalent in mesos-chronos?